# cloning a branch from github in my local pc

Tags: git, github

I created a branch (not a master branch, called `second`) in github and I added some files to it. Now I want to clone this branch to my local pc but it clones the master branch and in master branch I do  not have that particular file.

How can I have only second branch in my pc?

Comment: pc , you mean your OS is Windows ? and you have github software installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
git fetch REMOTE_NAME
```

where `REMOTE_NAME` is how you called the remote, if you don't know this chances are it's called `origin`. Once you've done that you should do

```
git checkout second
```

since now the branch is in your local repository.

Comment: Thanks indeed :) it works! Now when I want to push to second branch it is still in master branch.. that is what I did. cd myfolder / git init / git add myfile.txt /git status -- > on branch master. but I want to push in second branch.

Comment: If you want to have some changes in your second branch then switch to it and do the changes there, once done you should commit and `git push origin second`. If the answer helped you don't forget to upvote and mark it as accepted, if you have more questions I'd suggest you to open a new question.

Comment: When i go one level up to the main folder by cd .. and I do git branch it shows that I am on second branch, (*second, master) but when I do cd myfolder and do git status it says #on branch master. but I want to be still in second branch. why is it happening? I am afraid to replace the master branch files with my files, that is what happend last time, thats why I want to be still in second branch

Comment: I don't know about that, seems a lot strange, are you sure you are not changing branches meanwhile?

Comment: Then I would suggest you to post another question with your project directory structure and details about how and when this problem arises